# Using qBittorrent is there a way to skip downloading junk files?

Tags: bittorrent

I just read [How to edit the list of files to download in a .torrent file?](https://superuser.com/questions/483285/how-to-edit-the-list-of-files-to-download-in-a-torrent-file) and it show's how you can edit a torrent file but it would not work anymore.

So my question, is once the all file's are finished downloading, is there a way to delete the junk files automatically?

Secondary question, is it possible to not have incomplete download's in my completed download's folder?

I always have tons of files with extension of !QB, in my completed download's folder, when they shouldn't be there. Since that interefere's with my automation to move completed downloads.

Is there a setting I need to do?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: My first goal is to automatically delete junk files, rather than having to manually select which files to download.

Comment: I would like a way to blanket ban download of files based on a wildcard file name pattern. E.g "torrent downloaded from"

Answer (score 4):

On the "Content" tab of your torrent you can set files to "do not download" priority.

In options you can configure it to keep complete and incomplete file in different dirs and enable/disable addition of .!qb extension to incomplete files.

It looks like this
[image]

Comment: I have two seperate folders specified in settings, but it seems to ignore that. Some of the settings aren't very clear.

Comment: This seems to be a known and longstanding bug. Those setting randomly work sometimes, like every other time (not for some people and not for others).

Comment: It ***always*** seems to work for me. Maybe I am just lucky

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/C0nw0nk/qBittorrent

I did write a script for this so you can blacklist files inside the torrent you do not want to download.

https://github.com/C0nw0nk/qBittorrent/blob/main/qbt.cmd#L38

It is the only way currently until qBittorrent develop it as a feature you will have to use a script.

Answer (score 0):

From qBittorrent's github Frequently Asked Questions

**I configured qBittorrent to not download some files in a torrent but they still appear on my hard disk, why is that?**

As you may know, a torrent is split into pieces of equal size that do not take files into consideration.
As a consequence, a piece can contain information relative to more than one file and qBittorrent only operates at piece level.
Because of this, if two files are adjacent and you choose to download only one of them, it is likely that the filtered one will be partially downloaded and thus appear on the hard-disk.

Comment: If you are quoting somewhere, please link to the source, and indicate clearly what part of your answer is a quote.